# Javascript Promises not working As Expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise, nonblocking

[image: Code and output Screenshot]

Hi i am trying to understand the concept of Promises in javascript.And have written this very simple program to do so .But the order of the output that i am getting is not what i expected.I was expecting that output order to be :

after func

outside eveything

0

0

495510

496506

497503

498501

**but i am getting the opposite of this**.I was expecting the above output because the code should be non-blocking as i am using a Promise.So the program should just continue executing .But from the real output i am getting it seems that the code is blocking code after func() is called. What am i doing wrong here?What should i change to get the desired output and what am i missing here?The code is written below with a screenshot attached above.

```
function func() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
        console.log(sum)
        sum+=i;
    }
    if(sum>200){
    resolve("Greater than ")
    }
    else{
        reject("Error:")
    }
})}
async function somefunction(){
    func()
    console.log("after func")
}
somefunction()
console.log("Outside everything")
```

Comment: Why is there an `async`? This doesn't add anything useful to your script.

Comment: Yeah it is there because i will use await before the func() statement if needed.I am just trying different things here to understand the concept better.Also for this demo i removed the await from in front of func().

Comment: "*the code should be non-blocking as i am using a Promise*" - no. Code is non-blocking when it uses some natively asynchronous stuff like timeouts, but your code doesn't. The `new Promise` constructor doesn't make anything non-blocking

Answer (score 0):

This is probably how it should looked

```
(async () => {
  // Using IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) as somefunction is async
  // But this is optional 
  function func () {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      // add sum variable
      let sum = 0
      for (let i = 0;i < 10;i++) { // for simplicity using 10
        sum += i
        console.log(sum)
      }
      if (sum > 5) {  // for simplicity using 5
        resolve('Greater than ')
      } else {
        reject('Error:')
      }
    })
  }
  async function somefunction () {
    try {
      // await func to be resolved
      const result = await func() // get result from resolve call
      console.log(result)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e) // get result from reject call
    }
    console.log('after func')
  }
  // wait until somefunction finishes, its necessary to void console.log('Outside everything') being called immediately
  await somefunction() 
  console.log('Outside everything')
})()
```

And this is the actual log

```
➜ node demo.js
0
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
Greater than 
after func
Outside everything
```

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to understand here is that promises are always guaranteed to resolve at the end of the current run (i.e. the current execution block), even if they are seemingly resolved 'immediately'. That is:

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('a'));
console.log('b'); //"b", "a" - NOT "a", "b"
```

(Further reading: I discuss this concept more in [part 3](https://mitya.uk/articles/javascript-promises-part-3#miscellaneous) of my 3-part guide to Promises.)

With this in mind, let's see what's happening.

First of all you call `func()`. Don't be confused by `async` prepended to it; it's still a synchronous function call, and so its operations happen first. `async` merely acts as a "heads up" that its body will do asynchronous operations - not that it *itself* is asynchronous.

The first of those operations involves promises, so we know, based on the above, that they will resolve last, after our synchronous `console.log()`s. With these pushed to the back of the queue, we move to the second operation, which is to output "after func".

That's the end of the function, so execution flow returns to the caller scope of that function. The next thing it finds to do is output "outside everything".

And that's the end of the execution flow ("current run", remember) - and so the promises (numbers) are now free to resolve and be output.

Comment: I added console.log() inside func() because i was trying to simulate lets say some task inside func().And that task will take some time.And while that task is going on inside the func() , our main program will just go on and on doing its own work.That is why i expected **Outside everything** to be printed first or second and then all the console.log() from inside func().Is there a way to do it? That is while some heavy calculation is going on inside func() everything else in the program is going with it and not after func() is completed.

Answer (score -1):

Async functions and Promises are returned **before the function finishes**.

Here's the fixed version of your code:

```
function func() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
        console.log(sum)
        sum+=i;
    }
    if(sum>200){
    resolve("Greater than ")
    }
    else{
        reject("Error:")
    }
})}
async function somefunction(){
    func()
    console.log("after func")
}
somefunction().then(() => {
    console.log("Outside everything")
})
```

Comment: That gives the exact same output as it gave in my case(in the screenshot).Also this is not what i wanted.I understand completely what you've done as i am used to using Promises that way(as you showed).But it is not what i wanted. I wanted Outside everything to be printed first or second on the screen.Like a nonblocking code and using await here is not required.Thanks anyways